# JavaFX Why VBox change it's cells size when adding more childrens

Tags: javafx

I'm making chat application. The chat content display in VBox, each message in Label. The problem happens when I add more labels to the VBox - I see that all the message labels resized to smaller size, with no consideration to their content. Can someone tell me how can I solve this problem? thanks
Code for example:
FXML:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="245.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="chatwithnolist.FXMLController">
   <children>
  <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" layoutX="147.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="351.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="49.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <content>
        <VBox fx:id="vbox" prefHeight="348.0" prefWidth="596.0" spacing="5.0" />
     </content>
  </ScrollPane>
  <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonPressed" text="add to vbox" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```
@FXML
private ScrollPane scrollPane;
@FXML
private VBox vbox;
@FXML
private Button button;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
}    

@FXML
private void buttonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
    Label label = new Label("bla bla\nbla bla\nbla bla\n");
    label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #a1f2cd; "
            + "-fx-padding: 10;\n"
            + "-fx-spacing: 5;");
    vbox.getChildren().add(label);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `ScrollPane` inside a `VBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Text` inside `BorderPane` instead of `Label` and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The VBox can automatically grow depending on its parent container and its layount constraints. But I guess your problem is the following: Your VBox's content is growing larger than the available application size.

This is usually a case for using the [ScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html).

But in your case I would recommend to use the [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html). It can handle extreme amounts of contents without any performance drawbacks, providing the scrolling feature out of the box.

---

Edit:

The following code demonstrates a working example with ListView:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(strings);

        Button addMessage = new Button("Press me");
        addMessage.setOnAction(ev -> strings.add("bla bla\nbla bla\nbla bla\n"));
        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(addMessage);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(listView);
        root.setTop(toolbar);
        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

Edit #2:

Same Example Code, but with VBox + ScrollPane instead of ListView:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();

        Button addMessage = new Button("Press me");
        addMessage.setOnAction(ev -> vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("bla bla\nbla bla\nbla bla\n")));
        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(addMessage);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(new ScrollPane(vbox));
        root.setTop(toolbar);
        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using ScrollPane for the VBox's parent but it doesn't matter, the cells still shrinking

Comment: In that case it would be useful to see a code example showing your problem.

Comment: Fixed! Please help me!! :(

Comment: I added a working example with a ListView. Now you can go on: Move parts to FXML, add custom Cell Renderers, etc. Have fun :-)

Comment: I cant use ListView for many reasons - there is no way to use the VBox?

Comment: Added second example.

Comment: I dont understand how the second example helps me :/